Dataclasses and inheritance
I have the following classes:
from enum import Enum
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json
from typing import Optional, Dict, List

class RBACRoleType(str, Enum):
    BUILT_IN = "BuiltInRole"
    CUSTOM = "CustomRole"

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class RBACRole:
    assignableScopes: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
    createdBy: str = None
    createdOn: str = None
    description: str = None
    id: str = None
    name: str = None
    roleName: str = None
    roleType: RBACRoleType = None
    type: str = None
    updatedBy: str = None
    updatedOn: str = None
    permissions: List[Dict] = field(default_factory=list)

> Blockquote

class ResourceType(str, Enum):
    MANAGEMENT_GROUP = "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups"
    SUBSCRIPTION = "/subscriptions"
    RESOURCE_GROUP = "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Resource:
    id: str = None
    displayName: Optional[str] = None
    name: str = None
    type: ResourceType = None
    custom_role_definitions: List[RBACRole] = field(default_factory=list)
    children: Optional[List['Resource']] = field(default_factory=list)

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class ResourceGroup(Resource):
    type: ResourceType = field(default=ResourceType.RESOURCE_GROUP)
    location: str = None
    tags: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = field(default_factory=dict)
    properties: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = field(default_factory=dict)

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Subscription(Resource):
    type: ResourceType = field(default=ResourceType.SUBSCRIPTION)

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class ManagementGroup(Resource):
    type: ResourceType = field(default=ResourceType.MANAGEMENT_GROUP)

Here is some sample data:
{
    "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/afstestgroupSchema",
    "displayName": "afstestgroupSchema",
    "name": "afstestgroupSchema",
    "type": "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "/subscriptions/ee536581-6700-4a38-bcdf-7c297f47bbde",
            "displayName": "dummy-testapacregion1-sandbox",
            "name": "ee536581-6700-4a38-bcdf-7c297f47bbde",
            "type": "/subscriptions",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/ee536581-6700-4a38-bcdf-7c297f47bbde/resourceGroups/testapacregion1-network-vnet-sandbox",
                    "displayName": null,
                    "name": "testapacregion1-network-vnet-sandbox",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
                    "children": [],
                    "location": "southeastasia",
                    "tags": {
                        "ApplicationName": "Azure Networks",
                        "BusinessFunction": "connectivity",
                        "BusinessOwner": "wt629206",
                        "BusinessUnit": "enterprise-hosting-services",
                        "Environment": "SandBox",
                        "ParentCIID": "P057310732",
                        "TechnicalOwner": "djp45988"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

The problem is with the nesting. When I'm reading a json file I'm losing all the children of type ResourceGroup fields (location, tags and properties):
# Read the JSON file
file_path = './backup/backup-rbac.json'
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    json_data = file.read()

# Deserialize the JSON content into a ManagementGroup object
management_group = ManagementGroup.from_json(json_data)

Also, I have problem when using ManagementGroup().from_dict(dict_data) since all the children are considered Resource.
I've tried using this and it works, but I feel like it's not the right way to do it:
def __post_init__(self):
    super().__post_init__()
    if self.children:
        for i, child in enumerate(self.children):
            if child.type == ResourceType.SUBSCRIPTION:
                self.children[i] = Subscription(**child.to_dict())
            elif child.type == ResourceType.MANAGEMENT_GROUP:
                self.children[i] = ManagementGroup(**child.to_dict())


please provide a [mcve].

I've added some sample data

Having type be a str in the parent class, but ResourceType in the child class, seems like a problem.

Thanks for noticing that typo, but that still doesn't solve the issue

I've edited the question to add even more context

Again, please provide a [mcve]. This isn't complete (what's ManagementGroup.from_json?) and it sure doesn't look minimal.

I have implemented a helper function resource_decoder that checks the type field in the JSON data and returns an instance of the appropriate subclass (ManagementGroup, Subscription, ResourceGroup, or Resource).
@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Resource:
    id: str = None
    displayName: Optional[str] = None
    name: str = None
    type: ResourceType = None
    custom_role_definitions: List[RBACRole] = field(default_factory=list)
    children: Optional[List['Resource']] = field(default_factory=list, metadata=config(encoder=lambda x: [child.to_dict() for child in x], decoder=lambda x: [resource_decoder(child) for child in x]))

def resource_decoder(data: dict) -> Resource:
    resource_type = data.get("type")
    if resource_type == ResourceType.MANAGEMENT_GROUP.value:
        return ManagementGroup.from_dict(data)
    elif resource_type == ResourceType.SUBSCRIPTION.value:
        return Subscription.from_dict(data)
    elif resource_type == ResourceType.RESOURCE_GROUP.value:
        return ResourceGroup.from_dict(data)
    else:
        return Resource.from_dict(data)

I'm pretty sure this is not the best solution, I need some advice on how to do this properly.

Due to your uncertainty and the wording of your explanatory text, this is probably best added to your question as an edit rather than submitted as an answer. Good luck!
